# Angular wiring with controller - beginner

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm following this tutorial : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i9MHigUZKEM

I'm 46:32 minutes in and here is my code so far :

```
<html data-ng-app="demoApp">

<body data-ng-controller="SimpleController"} ]">

    <div data-ng-controller="SimpleController">
        Name : <br /> <input type="text" data-ng-model="name" /> {{name}} <br />

        <ul>
            <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:name | orderBy:'city'">
                {{ cust.name | uppercase }} - {{cust.city | lowercase}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        //[] means no dependencies
        var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', [])

        demoApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.when('/', {
                controller : 'SimpleController',
                templateUrl : 'View1.html'
            }).when('/partial2', {
                controller : 'SimpleController',
                templateUrl : 'View2.html'
            })
            .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/'});
        });

        function SimpleController($scope) {

            $scope.customers = [ {
                name : 'John Smith',
                city : 'Pheonix'
            }, {
                name : 'Jane Doe',
                city : 'San Francisco'
            }, {
                name : 'Derek Doe',
                city : 'New York'
            } ];
        }

        demoApp.controller('SimpleController', SimpleController);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

But the code is not working as expected. The code looks fine to me but there is obviously something wrong. Am I missing an import or the code incorrect >
Error :

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/undefined/$injector/modulerr?p0=demoApp&p1=Erro…paces%2F04072013%2FAngularJSFirst%2FWebContent%2Fangular.min.js%3A32%3A427)
```

Comment: Use unminified version for development...has more verbose error output that is removed in minified version

Comment: Your ng-controller attribute has some unnecessary characters after it. Should the angular script import be in the head of the document?

Comment: also no reason for nesting same controller in markup

Comment: also depending on the version of Angular you are using, you may need to inject 'ngRoute' into your 'demoApp' module.

Comment: this line has obviously syntax errors: `<body data-ng-controller="SimpleController"} ]">` remove the extra `} ]"` at the end...

Answer (score 2):

As per all the comments here's a quick summary to might solve your problem(S)

-1 Include `<script src="angular.min.js"></script>` in the `<head>` of your document or at the end. Use uniminifed version for development and switch to minified for production.

-2 Don't nest your controllers. You have `data-ng-controller="SimpleController"` in both your `<body>` tag and its child `div` you only need to declare it once. Also there is a typo in your `<body>` tag not sure if it was just when you cpoied your code over.

-3 I'm not sure what version of Angular you're using but I believe in the latest version, ngRoute is not included so you have to declare it as a dependency of your app as such `var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', ['ngRoute'])`. I'm not sure, but I believe this is the source of your error.